# serve nodejs and laravel on same config file

Tags: nginx

i have node and laravel app both serves html file, and the url works like:

myapp-laravel.com -> laravel app

myapp-laravel.com/node/ -> nodejs app

the laravel app works fine, but nodejs can't serve the html and it gives me error "cannot get /node/ file" as plaintext.It works if i separate the config but i want to access it with my main domain (myapp-laravel.com) so i have to put it on same config

```
upstream node {
    server localhost:3201;
}

server {
    root /var/www/html/laravel-app;
    index index.php index.html
    server_name myapp-laravel.com
   
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

    location /node/ {
        alias /var/www/html/node;
        try_files $uri @node;
    }
    
    location @node {
        proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a by examples that show URL and where exactly that URL would fetch its content. It is unclear from your question what exact request isn't working like you want.

Comment: okay i will update the question